# The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I ran into an error which I cannot seem to solve, I'd really appreciate if someone could give me a helping hand.  I am following a tutorial on youtube and it works for them when they use JPanel, but not for me.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Also this:

[image]

Code:

```
package tfh.physics;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ForceList extends JPanel 
{

}
```

Comment: First try to rebuild and clean your project in Eclipse. You can rebuild by right-clicking your project in the package explorer, and clean it by clicking on the Project menu item.

Comment: For example: [link](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=207). Also, I've added an Eclipse tag to your question since this is likely an Eclipse set up problem.

Comment: I cleaned the code however the error still remains. Perhaps it has something to do with buildpath or the fact that I'm using jre 1.8.0? I'm really unsure, but thanks for taking the time to help me sir.

Comment: Guys it's fixed :P, had to remove Java version 8.0 and the Development Kit 1.8, just re installed 1.7 and it's working! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: 1.7? nah, that won't do as you'll miss all the goodies in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all old unused Java versions from your Java installation directory. Make sure your JDK and JRE are the same version, and bit.

If that doesn't work, make sure you have your PATH variable configured correctly.

You can download the Java Development Kit at [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

**EDIT: I see that you have fixed your problem. However, like @Hovercraft Full Of Eels mentioned, you WILL miss out on all of the "goodies". I strongly recommend you update to Java 8, both JRE and JDK. Keep in mind JDK comes with JRE, so you don't need to download both.**